# Timeline and clockview model did not appear in cesiumjs

Tags: geoserver, wms, cesium

I have performed coding to the particular html file and it contain the code to access the wms layers from the Geoserver. However, when I run the html file, I am not able to see a clock view model and the timeline. Here is my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Use correct character set. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Tell IE to use the latest, best version. -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!-- Make the application on mobile take up the full browser screen and disable user scaling. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Blue Marble</title>
  <script src="../Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
 <style>
      @import url(../Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);
      html, body, #cesiumContainer {
          width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
      }
  </style>
</head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
  <script>

var widget = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer', {
    clock: clock
});

var clock = new Cesium.Clock({
   startTime : Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601("2013-12-25"),
   currentTime : Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601("2013-12-25"),
   stopTime : Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601("2013-12-26"),
   clockRange : Cesium.ClockRange.LOOP_STOP,
   clockStep : Cesium.ClockStep.SYSTEM_CLOCK_MULTIPLIER
});
var url='http://localhost:8090/geoserver/geog4/wms'; 
var layers = widget.scene.globe.imageryLayers;
    layers.removeAll();
    layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
        url : url,        
        layers: 'geog4:geotiff_coverage'
    }));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CesiumWidget` is only a container for the scene and its globe, it does not contain any other sub-widgets like the `Animation` or `Timeline` widgets.

Replace this code:

```
var widget = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer', {
    clock: clock
});
```

With the `Viewer` instead:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    clock: clock
});
```

The `Viewer` widget contains a `CesiumWidget`, `Animation`, `Timeline`, and several other sub-widgets, along with a `Cesium.DataSourceCollection` and related logic to drive it.  There are Viewer constructor options to disable any subwidgets that are not wanted.